# how do I get sequence of 'false' in an array

Tags: c++, sequence, eigen

I am the beginner of C++, and any help will be very appreciated.
here is the code i can run successfully:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <iostream>
using namespace Eigen;
main(){
  bool findIn=false;
  RowVectorXd A(10);
  A<<false,true,false,true,true,false,false,false,true,true;
  std::cout << A << std::endl;
  for (int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
    if(A(i)==findIn){
      std::cout << i << std::endl;                
    }          
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

the result is {0,2,5,6,7}, and I want to design a function, the code is as follows:

```
int seq(bool findIn, VectorXd &resdX){
  VectorXd A;
  for(int i=0;i<resdX.size();i++){
    if(resdX(i)==findIn){
       A =A+i;                  
    }                                                    
  }
  return(A);     
}
```

I want this function to return result like that {0,2,5,6,7}.But I don`t know how to set up a array to save the result or is there a function just like 'which' in R software to produce sequence above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand what are you looking for.
If you want just to print a sequence of `int`egers indexing `findIn` values you might code:

```
void seq(bool findIn, VectorXd &resdX) { // not int
  std::cout << "{ ";
  for(int i=0;i<resdX.size();i++) // go inside the array
    if(resdX(i)==findIn) // if you find that resdX(i) value equals findIn value
       std::cout << i << " "; // print i index

  std::cout << "}" << std::endl; // at the end prints a new line
}
```

**EDIT1:**

Try to adapt the following snippet:

```
#include <list>
...

std::list<int> seq(bool findIn, VectorXd& resdX) {
    std::list<int> l;
    for(int i=0; i<resdX.size(); i++) {
        if (resdX(i) == findIn) {
            l.push_back(i);
        }
    }
    return l;
}

void print_seq(std::list<int> list_) {
  std::cout << "{ ";
  std::list<int>::iterator it = list_.begin();
  for (; it != list_.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
  std::cout << " }\n";
}
```

Comment: I want to get the position sequence of 'false' in an array as a vector.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a vector of integers:

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> seq(bool findIn, VectorXd &resdX)
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    for(int i=0;i<resdX.size();i++) {
        if (resdX(i) == findIn) {
            v.push_back(i);     
        }                                                    
    }
    return v;     
}
```

You can then print its contents by iterating through it:

```
std::vector<int> result = seq(false, A);
for (int i : result) std::cout << i << '\n';
```

Comment: when i run your code, error will occur. "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '<' token"  'expected',' or ';'before '<' token'. how could i repair it?

Comment: if you are not using `std` namespace, each `vector<int>` has to be preceded by `std::`. You can avoid use of `std` by putting under `#include <vector>` the line `using namespace std`.